# Writing feature test for protected endpoints in Laravel 10 authenticated by Auth0

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, jwt, auth0

**Situation:**

I have a Laravel 10 app that uses was setup as 'Regular web application' in Auth0. I want to write feature test for protected routes but Im not sure how I perform authentication. I cant find documentation for this.

**Detail of my setup**

- Laravel 10
- Auth0 7.8

I followed https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/interactive to setup laravel with auth0

- I have 'api/posts' endpoint that only admins can access. Admin is defined in auth0 with permission.

At this point I need direction in this, Im new with auth0 integration.

Thank you so much in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this in a few different ways, and this applies to writing API tests in general, not solely connected to Auth0.

1. If your APIs are protected with JWTs, you can use JWT libraries to forge your own tokens when running tests. This allows you to create tokens with specific needs for the tests — you can create expired tokens, tokens with invalid or missing claims, signed with wrong certificates, etc. to make sure that your APIs handle these accordingly.
2. If you need to test code that runs some flows, or maybe you use opaque tokens and perform token introspection in your APIs, etc. then you could use a service like WireMock (the standalone version) to create mocked endpoints. Your tests can then call the endpoints as they would normally, but you don't have to use the real thing.
3. If you want to test some frontend flows then you can use tools like Cypress to create browser-based tests. These tests can perform logins and use the established session or obtained tokens to run further tests.
4. If you need to obtain real tokens from a system and don't want to use cypress, you can create scripts that use curl to obtain the tokens. For example, have a look at this script my colleague wrote some time ago: https://github.com/curityio/oauth-agent-kotlin-spring/blob/main/test/end-to-end/login.sh It uses curl to perform login at an authorization server and get an OAuth access token.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I will test these methods out. I have a makeshift solution right now that i do not trust very much but this is a great starting point.